# html.BeginForm MVC 5 causing form tag CSS issue

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I don't understand this issue, if I include: -

```
<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post))
{
     <div>
        <form>
            <br />
            <div>
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Log in" />
            </div>
        </form>
     </div>
}
```

The form CSS doesn't render properly

```
<form>
    <br />
    <div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Log in" />
    </div>
</form>

form
{
    background:#f0f0f0;
    padding:4% 3%;
}
```

But if I put the `HTML.BeginForm` tag  just before the `<form>` HTML

```
  <div> 
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <form>
              ....
        </form>
    }
  </div>
```

It works,

Can someone explain this needs to be done this way?

Comment: are you using bootstrap? It can override your div style properties inside 'panel-body'

Comment: I am using it, is there a way to stop it to override?

Comment: just created page with your exambple, and there is no style overrided. Which css rules ignored?

Comment: Thank you @aleha, I had to do more investigation as you are right, it isnt the bootstrap that being ignored, its the <form> tag contents, basically the css background should only fill the login div, but it does the entire panel-body div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't nest froms in html. It can lead you to odd behaviours and that's probably what's happening

Comment: I see, I changed it to a <div> and yeah same result, so why do people still use the <form> tag then?

Comment: "div" tag is a generic element in html. You use a "form" when you want to submit contact the server (Request a page, Send values to the server, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Everithing looks like normal:

```css
#login
{
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0%;
    transition:opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="login">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <form>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Log in" />
                </div>
            </form>
            <div style="position:relative; left:30%">
                <!--@Html.ValidationSummary()-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```